# Why does Polygon of shapely reset the kernel in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, shapely

I am trying to use shapely in jupyter.

```
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, LineString, GeometryCollection
import numpy as np
from shapely.ops import linemerge, unary_union, polygonize
```

The following works fine

```
pt = Point(10, 10)
pt1 = Point(100, 101)
pt
```

But when I use the `Polygon` or the `LineString` attribute the kernel is reseted:

```
p1 = Polygon([(0,0), (1,1), (1,0)])
p2 = Polygon([(0,1), (1,0), (1,1)])
print(p1.intersects(p2))
```

```
ln = LineString([(0, 1), (20, 100), (100, 3), (120, 102), (200, 5)])
ln
```

Could someone tell me how to manage that?